# Trying to install web3 using python fails

Tags: python, ethereum

I am using this [tutorial](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/a-developers-guide-to-ethereum-part-one/) and I am trying to install `Web3.py` by using the command `pip install web3`, this will generate an error:
[image]

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting web3
  Using cached web3-4.8.1.tar.gz (96 kB)
ERROR: Package 'web3' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.5.3,<4'
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: @Theshape thanks mate!

Comment: your very welcome pardner :D

Comment: The error is telling you that your Python version needs to be at least `3.5.3`. It's not clear why you'd want to use Python 2, which has been deprecated for a year and a half. You should try using `pip3` instead of `pip`. Does that work?

Comment: and it is also tellin you to update to python 3.x

Comment: I have done the update but I had to use pip3 so thanks alot!

Comment: still run into errors and couldnt do it this way!

Comment: I suggest you open a generic question "Cannot install Python 3 packages" as this issue is related of not having functioning or experience of running Python 3 on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the python3.7 version.

It's a success to install on my side.

[image]